# v-on:mouseover condition VueJS 1.0.21

Tags: vue.js, events, conditional-statements, ternary

I'm trying to add condition to trigger mouseover, only if `minState == true` .
So far here's what I have tried already yet it didn't worked:

> v-on:mouseover="minState == true ? collapsableSideBar : null"

.

> v-on="minState == true ? { mouseover: collapsableSideBar } : {}"

.

> v-on="{ mouseover: minState == true ? collapsableSideBar : null }"

Comment: Why not just create 2 components with 2 different event handling and show them based on minState value.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. By the way sorry my mistake "collapsableSideBar" was a function on my method so it should be ```collapsableSideBar() ``` it is now working. Wasted so much time I missed this one.

Comment: Right. `collalapsableSidebar` will simply return the function but not invoke it. Glad you noticed it.